# write a function to add multiple columns with quotient of a division in R

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns

I would like to add a series of columns with the quotient of a division. My dataframe looks like this:

```
views01  users01 views02 users02 
   2        4       4       1             
   4        5       11      2              
   5        2       9       4
```

I'd like to write a piece of code that computes the division views(n)/users(n) and adds columns to the df, like so:

```
 views01  users01 views02 users02  views_per_user01  views_per_user02
   2        4       4       1            0.5                4 
   4        5       11      2            0.8               5.5
   5        2       9       4            2.5               2.25
```

For the time being, I've created a line of code like that:

```
df$views_per_user01=df$views01/df$users01
df$views_per_user02=df$views02/df$users02
```

For each of the cases, but I'd like to shrink it to a single line.
Thank you.

Comment: Any particular language you'd like to do this in?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it assuming that your data frame will be sorted as per your example,

```
cbind(df, sapply(unique(sub('\\D+', '', names(df))), 
                       function(i) Reduce('/', df[,grepl(i, sub('\\D+', '', names(df)))])))

#  views01 users01 views02 users02  01   02
#1       2       4       4       1 0.5 4.00
#2       4       5      11       2 0.8 5.50
#3       5       2       9       4 2.5 2.25
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`'s `mutate` function to append the new columns:

```
library(dplyr) 
mutate(df, views_per_user01=views01/users01,                
           views_per_user02=views02/users02)
```